# '@Given' not applicable to method error

Tags: jbehave

I'm writing my first lines for jbehave.. and already bumping with this error:

```
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.Steps;
public class UserDetailsInputSteps extends Steps
{
    @Given("UI for user profile")
    public void launchUI(){
    }
}
```

Error: '@Given' not applicable to method

Cannot get what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think you need/want to extend Steps, it should just be a pojo.

Comment: Well, thats what I tried first. Still the same error.

Comment: Could be something with intellij? missing dependencies? .. (maven+intellij+jbehave project)